# The engine showing only few rows in report - How to solve?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a problem with JasperReports' report. I want to create a report that produces for each Database entry, on sheet. When I create it, it shows me only a few rows. Maybe there is a parameter to set in the iReport designer.

Comment: Provide more details. What do you expect the report to look like? What does it actually look like? What does the query statement return when run directly against the database?

Answer (score 0):

A number of things to check:

- Change the height of your report. Do you get more rows to appear? What about the height of your band? Does it change the results?
- Check which band you have your content in. Some bands behave differently than others. Header/Footer/etc bands do not expand.
- Check your input (the data from your query / xml datasource / whatever). Make sure that what you think is the input to your report really is.

Otherwise, likely we'll need more information. If you could upload an example jrxml that would help.